# WYSIWYG Editor (CKEditor)'s Code-saving option is more detrimental than helpful

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm using a CKEditor to build a html page, when adding certain elements, specifically "" It likes to chew up and discard it as if it was bad code.

Is there anyway to avoid this? It will run the code fine, but as soon as I go back into the editor, it's chewed up.

**Code I'm using (HTML):**

```
<div class="nav">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle"/>
  <label for="nav-toggle">&equiv;</label>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab 4.. etc</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Are there any tags I can use to incase it that tell the editor not to touch this code?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, and you are trying to use CKEditor to design and build an HTML site, it probably means you are not using a proper tool for the job. See this article about what CKEditor is, what it is not and how it works: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basics

Comment: Well to rephrase it, my company has a framework we built using cakephp, the site is already built by default, the ckeditor is for content, but you can also apply some classes and such to enhance the layout of the site, if that makes any sense?